# FlatBuffer schema design for frameworks

Tags: flatbuffers

I'm looking for advice on structuring FlatBuffer schemas for a framework which allows users to extend the data types defined by the framework, but also allows the framework developers to add new fields when new versions of the framework are published.

My original thinking was that when you create a project using this framework, it would generate several FlatBuffer schema files which you could then edit for your specific project. You could then compile the schemas and start developing code using the framework APIs.

However, this becomes a problem when the framework developers decide to add fields to the base types. As you probably know, FlatBuffers requires that any additional fields be appended to the end (or at least have a higher ID than other fields). So there is a conflict between the additions made by the framework developer and the framework user.

One possible solution would be to have a set of 'non-user-extensible' types that are owned by the framework creator, and which should not be modified by users of the framework; and these types would then be embedded within the data types defined by the framework user. However, given the restrictions on fields changing size, I am not sure if this would even work.

I'm also willing to hear alternatives to using flatbuffers if it turns out that there is no good solution otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In retrospect (answering my own question two years later), it seems that FlatBuffers was not the right choice for my use case. These days I'm using a combination of msgpack (in cases where I care about byte-size) and JSON (in cases where I don't) and I'm pretty happy with each.

Answer (score 1):

To have open ended extension like that, you should really have the framework authors and users work in two separate tables.. where one can own the other. There is no good way to extend a single table if all contributors aren't sharing the schema in source control.

If these extensions must be in a single object for whatever reason, then Protocol Buffers is more flexible than FlatBuffers, since it doesn't require adjacent field ids. You can simply say that all field ids >=1000 are for framework users, for example.